# Linking dual (iphoneos and watchos) frameworks with same product name

Tags: xcode, xcode7, ios-frameworks, watchos-2, watchos

I recently had to duplicate my own frameworks to be able to link them from the native watchOS 2 extension, because the platform is different. So for every framework X I have an X-watchos counterpart.
Everything works fine in the simulator and when building directly to my devices, and it wasn't until I tried to archive that I got this linking error:

[image: Linking error]

I ran `lipo -i` on the built watchOS framework and sure enough, its archs are `arm7` and `arm64` instead of `armv7k`.

When I looked further into the built directory I noticed this:

[image: Derived data structure]

Both versions are symlinks to the same file, and because the have the same product name, they're being overridden. I could make them have different names, but that would make `import`ing them really cumbersome.

*Note that this is not a problem for 3rd-party frameworks because `Carthage` is already building them in separate directories.*

*EDIT 08/22/2015: I've filed a radar with a sample project: [http://www.openradar.me/22392501](http://www.openradar.me/22392501_)*

*EDIT 08/24/2015: This has been acknowledged in Xcode 7 Beta 6 release notes as a known issue:*

[image: known issue]

*EDIT 09/9/2015: Xcode 7.1 Beta release notes hint that this is fixed, but I haven't confirmed it yet.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working for me in Xcode 7.1.

Comment: Yup, I can confirm that this works as expected in 7.1 Beta 1 as well.

Comment: Finally are you using the same product name for each version (watch and iOS) of your framework or a different one?

Comment: On 7.1 I am using the same product name for each platform just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I’m using a similar configuration with my own frameworks, but I set a different name when creating it in each platform (MyFramework and MyFramework-watchOS). Don't forget to set a common product name manually (mine is MyFramework on both) in the build settings tab of each framework.

Comment: That is exactly my configuration: as I mentioned, the target names are different (X and X-watchos) but the product name is X.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I took an example from an Apple sample project "Lister" and from a last year video session about frameworks and It is working fine in one of my projects... Hope you find a solution soon

Comment: Could you link to that project? I'll take a look and maybe I'll see what's different there :)

Comment: Of course: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/Lister/Introduction/Intro.html  make sure you are downloading the latest version. Please let us know how you finally solved your issue

Comment: The sample project reproduces the same problem: `ListerforwatchOSiOSandOSX/Swift/ListerKit (watchOS)/ConnectivityListsController.swift:11:8: Module file was created for incompatible target armv7-apple-ios9.0: /Users/NachoSoto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Lister/BuildProductsPath/Release-watchos/ListerKit.framework/Modules/ListerKit.swiftmodule/arm.swiftmodule`. I've filed a radar with another sample project: http://www.openradar.me/22392501

Comment: It’s so well explained, let’s see if its fixed in the next Xcode beta version

Comment: Hey, as I suppose you had noticed (according to the release notes) that the new Xcode beta 6 seems to fix the Archiving issue. I have used a different product name for the watchOS framework as the notes indicates: “Workaround: Use a different product name (using the PRODUCT_NAME build setting) for the watchOS version of your framework. (22183332)” but after that, I’m not be able even to run the project because Xcode can’t find my framework’s headers files… I hope you get luckiest and can brin me some light on it.

Comment: Yeah I added an EDIT to my question. That's not really a fix, more like an acknowledgement of the bug. As I pointed out in the original question, changing product names was always on the table, but that makes everything a lot more complicated.